# Text leaving bootstrap container when mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a landing page with a container going down the middle. Everything looks great when window size is considered medium & large to bootstrap. But when I start changing the screen size, the text starts leaving the container.

[image: text leaving container]

Whats causing this to break?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">  
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
        <div class="logo">
            <!-- <img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="100" alt="BlackTie.co"> -->
        <h1> Test Title </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 w">
                <h1>BlackTie.co<br/>SMPL Theme.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 w tooltip-demo">
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Dribbble" href="http://dribbble.com/CarlosAlvarez"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/BlackTie_co"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Premium Themes" href="https://wrapbootstrap.com/user/Basicoh"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Free Themes" href="http://BlackTie.co"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Blog" href="http://freelance.postach.io"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email Me!" href="mailto:carlos@alvarez.is"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Newsletter" href="http://eepurl.com/Eck_T"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row w centered">
            <br>        
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <p>Believe in yourself! Have faith in your abilities! Without a humble but reasonable confidence in your own powers you cannot be successful or happy.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap";

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: grey;
  height:100%;
     width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 44%;
  position: relative;
}

/* Titles */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
}


/* Paragraph & Typographic */
p {
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Links */
a {
    color: #f39c12;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #7b7b7b;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

a:before,
a:after {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: color 0.1s ease-in, background 0.1s ease-in;
}

 hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
}

.w {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.w i {
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 12px;
}
```